# Using a has_one or belongs_to in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an `Business` model and an polymorphic `Address` model.

Each business has one main address but I would like advise on if it is better to have business `belong_to` the polymorphic model or if it is better to say each business has_one address

```rb
  belongs_to :main_location_address, class_name: "Address"

  has_one :main_location_address, class_name: "Address", as: :addressable
```

I have tried both but belongs_to still requires a addressable attribute for the address.

Also how would this work with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in the `Business` model and in the controller?

Comment: Is a main address optional or required? Can several businesses share the same address record and when it changes for one it also changes for all others)? Or is it a true 1:1 relation?

Comment: It is a 1:1 relationship. I will try to explain it better in the question.

Answer (score 1):

When representing relationships between entities it is important to reflect them in such a way that there is a logical resemblance to their real life counterparts.

It makes sense to say

> Business has one address/main address

rather than saying Business belongs to an address.

If you want to enforce a database constrain that a business can only have one address, you can create a unique index.
Since it is a polymorphic relation, I'm assuming it will be used by other models as well. If you do not need to enforce uniqueness for all models, you could go for a partial index to create a unique index only where addressable_type is Business.

```
class AddIndexToAddress < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :addresses, [:addressable_id, :addressable_type], unique: true, where: "addressable_type = 'Business'"
  end
end
```

This will work if you only need **strictly** one address per business.

It is not clear from the question if you have an additional relationship to manage multiple addresses for a business as well. In that case you need opt for a belong_to relationship with business containing the main address id.

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :main_address, class_name: 'Address', foreign_key: :address_id, optional: true
    has_many :addresses, class_name: 'Address', as: :addressable
end
```

You can add validations as per your business requirements.

Comment: The `belongs_to` assocation here must be optional (and the db column must be nullable). Otherwise you get into a circular chicken vs egg scenario since the address can't be created without a buisness and vice versa.

Comment: It should also be noted that partial indexes (`where: "addressable_type = 'Business'"`) are only supported for PostgreSQL and SQLite according to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Edited the answer. Since it was more of an asking for advise question I was focused on Why than how.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that a buisness actually can only have one main address then you need to use a `belongs_to` assocation and create a foreign key column.

```erb
class AddMainLocationAddressToBuisnesses < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_reference :buisnesses, :main_location_address, 
      null: true, 
      foreign_key: { to_table: :addresses }
  end
end
```

```erb
belongs_to :main_location_address, class_name: "Address", optional: true
```

Since the foreign key is stored on a column in the buisnesses table it can only have a single possible value per buisness.

```erb
has_one :main_location_address, class_name: "Address", as: :addressable
```

Will just fetch the first joined row off the addresses table. While you could monkey around and add `addresses.main_location` boolean column It provides no guarentee that there actually is just one main location address per addressable unless you for example write a custom constraint.

But then again if you're using a polymorphic assocation you have already tossed referential integrity out the window.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. How would the `has_one :main_location_address` guarantee that there are no other records pointing to that business record and it still only taking the top record if there are multiple ones.

To use that `AddMainLocationAddressToBuisnesses` migration wouldn't you have to use a belongs_to in the `Business` model? And how would that work when creating a new `Business` with an address when the address requires an addressable and the `Business` addressable has not been created yet?

Comment: `has_one :main_location_address` won't ever guarentee that there is just one record per buisness. While you could naively add a `has_one :main_location_address, ->{ where(main_location_address: true) }` scope to the assocation and uniqueness validations in the address model it won't actually guarentee that there are no duplicates.

Comment: That can only really be guarenteed by adding constraints to the database table which are database specific.

Comment: "And how would that work when creating a new Business with an address when the address requires an addressable and the Business addressable has not been created yet?" Thats kind of the pickle here. You need to insert the Business and Address and then update the buisiness with the address id.

Comment: I find this really weird because if I use the `had_one ...` and try to make a new `Business` with a new address associated vs using the `belongs_to ..` (using the migration main_location_address_id in the business) i get the following:

Comment: for the `had_one`:
bus = Business.new()
bus.build_main_location_address(line1: "Adsf", city: "adsf", state: "sdf")
and if i save it it will work and auto full the adressable_type but not the addressable_id because the Business has not been made.

Comment: for the `belongs_to`:
bus = Business.new()
bus.build_main_location_address(line1: "Adsf", city: "adsf", state: "sdf")
it will not save because it says it needs the addressable_id

Comment: I cannot make a discussion because i do not have enought xp but you might be able to start a discussion to continue this thread. I find this behavior very weird.

Comment: Sorry I made an omission in my answer where I forgot to make the column nullable and the association optional. Otherwise you get stuck in the chicken vs egg scenario.